# How to get the recipient addresses within an IPM.DistList?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2003, exchange-server-2003

I'm trying to get the recipient addresses within an IPM.DistList that is stored in a public folder (of type contacts) in Exchange 2003.

The typeName of the object is a Message (with a parent object being a Messages collection) and the messageType is "IPM.DistList".

I can find documentation about IPM.DistListItems. DistListItems documentation lists no parent possibilities in MSDN.

We have an Exchange 2003 info store with Public Folders. Within those Public Folders is a [sub]folder (that holds items of type "Contact") that has distribution lists (IPM.DistList's) that have contact entries, members of the list essentially.

I need to get the addresses of the members of the lists in the Public Folder sub-folder.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's been over a year, but I feel some obligation to answer this question now that I've found it. The answer was, I think, that no documentation exists on this secret bit of Exchange, but was able to iterate through the list of addresses within each ipm.distlist by something like this:

```
for a = 0 to list.count-1
   emladdress = list(a)(a).value
next
```

I don't know why "(a)(a)" works, but you have to have both of them there. And I don't actually remember if it was a zero-based index, so that's a guess. Good luck, and hopefully you can migrate your users off Exchange and into google apps. Seriously!